# Checkers Game (Java) Using Gridworld

Tags: java, gridworld

I have been working on creating a Checkers game in Eclipse using Gridworld. So far I have been only modifying red pieces. My goal is to be able to move() pieces and have them choose whether to jump or to step. Obviously, jumping (i.e. when the piece moves over a piece of the opposite color and then removing that piece from the grid) takes precedence over stepping. My problem is that whenever I try to move pieces that are either in the first two or last two columns I get an Illegal Out of Bounds error. Can anyone help me solve this? Please and thank you.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import info.gridworld.actor.Critter;
import info.gridworld.actor.Flower;
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

public class RedPieces extends Bug {
boolean jumped;

public RedPieces() {
    setColor(Color.red);
    setDirection(180);
    jumped = false;
}

public boolean canMove() {
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    if (gr == null)
        return false;
    Location loc1 = getLocation();
    if (getGrid().get(new Location(loc1.getRow() + 1, loc1.getCol() - 1)) == null || 
        getGrid().get(new Location(loc1.getRow() + 1, loc1.getCol() - 1)).getColor() == Color.black || 
        getGrid().get(new Location(loc1.getRow() + 1, loc1.getCol() + 1)) == null || 
        getGrid().get(new Location(loc1.getRow() + 1, loc1.getCol() + 1)).getColor() == Color.black) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean jump2(Location loc){
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    if (gr == null)
        return false;
    Location jump1 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 2, loc.getCol() - 2);
    Location jump2 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 2, loc.getCol() + 2);

    if( (gr.isValid(jump1)) && 
        (gr.get(jump1) == null) && 
        (gr.get(jump2) == null) && 
        (gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() -1)) instanceof BlackPieces) && 
        ((gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() + 1)) == null) || 
         (gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() + 1))) instanceof RedPieces))
    {
        gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() -1)).removeSelfFromGrid();
        moveTo(jump1);
        return true;
    }
    else if( (gr.isValid(jump2)) && 
             (gr.get(jump2) == null) && 
             (gr.get(jump1) == null) && 
             (gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() +1)) instanceof BlackPieces) && 
             ((gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() +1, loc.getCol() - 1)) == null) || 
              (gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() -1)) instanceof RedPieces)))
    {
        gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() +1)).removeSelfFromGrid();
        moveTo(jump2);
        return true;
    }
    else if((gr.isValid(jump1) && gr.get(jump1) == null) && 
            (gr.isValid(jump2) && gr.get(jump2) != null))
    {
        if(gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() -1)) instanceof BlackPieces)
        {
            gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() -1)).removeSelfFromGrid();
            moveTo(jump1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if((gr.isValid(jump2) && gr.get(jump2) == null) && 
            (gr.isValid(jump1) && gr.get(jump1) != null))
    {
        if(gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() +1)) instanceof BlackPieces)
        {
            gr.get(new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() +1)).removeSelfFromGrid();
            moveTo(jump2);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void move() {
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    if (gr == null)
        return;

    Location loc = getLocation();
    Location next1 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() - 1);
    Location next2 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() + 1);
    if (jump2(loc) == false) {
        if (gr.isValid(next2) && gr.get(next2) == null && 
            gr.isValid(next1) && gr.get(next1) != null)
        {
            moveTo(next2);
        }
        else if (gr.isValid(next1) && gr.get(next1) == null && 
                 gr.isValid(next1) && gr.get(next2) != null)
        {
            moveTo(next1);
        }
        else if (gr.isValid(next1) && gr.get(next1) == null && 
                 gr.isValid(next2) && gr.get(next2) == null)
        {
            moveTo(randomLoc(next1, next2));
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}

public static Location randomLoc(Location loc1, Location loc2) {
    double num = Math.random();
    if (num < 0.5)
        return loc1;
    else
        return loc2;
}

public void act() {
    if(canMove()) move();
}
}
```

Comment: Once thought to be of simple mistakes, it seem to show a case where the programmer over-complicates if-conditions. So I ask you reviewers who put this Q&A on hold, could you please wait until the questioner responds to my comments at least? Thank you.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help. As I am still new to StackOverflow (and quite honestly to Java itself) I was not aware that this question could be considered "off-topic". In my ignorance I assumed that the purpose of this site was to help people solve any of their programming issues with the help of fellow programmers. I agree that producing simple and clean code is an important skill for any programmer but as a ninth grader taking AP Computer Science I am still not totally fluent in the language, I sometimes go about the problem obtusely which leads to overcomplicated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to reformat your code for better readability.
By doing so, I have found a few potential bugs.

- In the `jump2()` method, the second `if` statement does not check the validity of `jump2`. It might be the cause of exception at `gr.get(jump2 == null)` condition in that `if` statement.
- The same logic applies to the subsequent `else if` statement. This time, you are not checking the validity of `jump1`.
- In the `move()` method, the first `else if`, you only check the validity of `next1` twice which seems a bug.  Please find it in the reformatted code in your question.

Overall, I think you need to modify the `if` conditions as simple(readable) as possible.  Reformatting will help, too.

[Added] Two minor things.

- In the `canMove()` method, you use `gr` only at the first `if` statement. You are using `getGrid()` instead of `gr` in the second `if` statement.
- Can you not avoid doing `new Location` everytime you get grid in the `if` statements? You are using those grids without checking their validity. Are you sure they are valid?  You might create them at the beginning of the method, check their validity, and use them in the `if` statements. It might help the readability of the `if` statements, too.

[Added more] `jump2()` method simplification sample

The following code ignores the other side of column (being invalid, null or red piece). It is on my assumption that it doesn't matter what the condition of other sides when one side is valid for jumping over a black piece.

```
public boolean jump2(Location loc){
    Grid<Actor> gr = getGrid();
    if (gr == null)
        return false;

    Location jump1 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 2, loc.getCol() - 2);
    Location jump2 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 2, loc.getCol() + 2);
    Location adjacent1 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() - 1);
    Location adjacent2 = new Location(loc.getRow() + 1, loc.getCol() + 1);

    // try one column
    if( gr.isValid(jump1))
    {
        if( (gr.get(jump1) == null) && 
            (gr.get(adjacent1) instanceof BlackPieces))
        {
            gr.get(adjacent1).removeSelfFromGrid();
            moveTo(jump1);
            return true;
        }
    }

    // try the other column
    if( gr.isValid(jump2))
    {
        if( (gr.get(jump2) == null) && 
             (gr.get(adjacent2) instanceof BlackPieces))
        {
            gr.get(adjacent2).removeSelfFromGrid();
            moveTo(jump2);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. In the interest of time, I did not get to simplifying the if statements but I did change the statement in the move() method and also added a statement that checks the validity of jump2 and jump1 in the jump2() method. So far I have not gotten any of the Out of Bounds exceptions however for some reason in some cases (specifically if the red piece is on the far right or far left side of the board) the piece chooses not to jump over the adjacent black piece as intended. Instead it simply stays put and does nothing. Any advice?

Comment: I think you can try to figure out what's happening by single stepping in debug mode.  One thing I am curious is : Is the checking for red piece or being it blank really needed before jumping over a black piece?  If that is not a rule to do so, then I suggest you to get rid of those additional conditions and see what happens.

Comment: I've added a sample `jump2()` method to my answer. It ignores conditions of other side when one side is valid for jumping.

Comment: Your code works very well and very clean. A few things that I noticed, however, is that your code always returns true so that now the pieces never just move, meaning that they either jump over if there is an adjacent black piece or they do not move at all. Also (and this is a minor detail) I am thinking about adding an additional else if that decides (if there are two possible choices to jump) which way to jump randomly. In your code, the piece will, if it has two options, always choose jump1. I will try to randomize this,. But thank you very much!

Comment: After a small modification to the jump method you gave me… I got the Checkers game to work! Thank you for all your help. Sorry if this sounds ignorant, but is there something i am supposed to do if you helped me answer the question i.e. give you points or click a button or something?

Comment: Were you able to randomize the jumps? I hope so.  If you feel my answer is acceptable, you can press the check mark on the left side of my answer. You can also increment the number if you feel the answer is useful.

Comment: I was able to randomize the jumps thanks to your help. Now I'm working on making the "flying king". Wish me luck!